# Could not execute onclick function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The onclick event is unable to execute using jQuery. I am providing my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('.checkboxdiv input:checkbox').attr('checked')) {
    $('.checkboxdiv input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
  }
  $('#carsval').click(function(){
      alert('did it');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="carsval" value="1" name="carsval" <?php if($isCar==1){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> >
```

Here inside the click function the alert is not executing after click on check box.

Comment: What is your problem? your code work correctly

Comment: You have to add jquery library before your code and your code must be on <script>your code goes here</script> block

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#carsval').on('click', function(){
    alert('did it');
});
```

Or this :

```
$(document).delegate('#carsval','click', function(){
    alert('did it');
});
```

Comment: @Mohammad - It may happen that it is not working in actual environment of user.

Comment: @Kashyap the .click() method is just the shorthand for .on('click'). Reference: https://api.jquery.com/click/ . I do not understand why one would work and the other would not

Comment: Your first example is literally just copied from what the OP already has, and `delegate()` was deprecated quite some time ago. You should not be using it. How this, frankly useless, answer has two upvotes, I can't even imagine.